# Is there a way to make this SQL injection work with the PHP authentication?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

```
//the $pw parameter uses md5

$qry="Select * from accts where un='$un' and pw='$pw' ";
$data=mysql_query($qry);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

If(!empty($row)){
  If($row["un"]==$un && $row["pw"]==$pw){
    //session and redirect
   }
}else{
Echo "The username and/or password is incorrect";
}
```

Comment: The SQL-injection itself will probably work with the `$un` parameter and the `--` operator. Search DuckDuckGo for basic SQL-injection techniques.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: My post answered the question indeed. It asks whether there is a way [to make sql injection work to circumvent authentication] and i said there is none. How is that not an answer? Correctnes is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

You must not only look at whether you can break the authentication scheme. The main problem with your query is that you can inject a query and have it executed. This allows you to basically enumerate the db with techniques of blind SQL injection. This will ultimately allow you to read out the password hash which might allow you to recover the original password....

Examples how you can do this can be found [here](http://www.sqlinjection.net/time-based/).

You are using time as a so called "covert channel", as a communication outside the regular channels.

Comment: Yup. Consider - if they know the admin username, they can set that, then put an ' in the PW to break the sql, add a clause to check if the first character is <something> and time(2) - if it takes two seconds, that is the first character.  Rinse and repeat for all characters (MD5 has known length).   Do not concat sql strings from untrusted data. Always use prepared statements.  Don't try to do anything fancy to make doing what you're doing safe - USE PREPARED STATEMENTS. That's what they are for.